# Reading an Excel File in Python to table

Tags: python, excel, typeerror

I'm having an issue with reading an excel file into a Python program:

This my read:

```
data = pd.read_excel('<file path>PriceOdometerV3.xlsx')
```

This is what I'm trying to read it into:

```
df_X = data[:, np.newaxis,2]
```

And this is the message I'm getting:

```
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), None, 2)' is an invalid key
```

Suggestions?  I'm know I'm missing a parameter that'll dice up the file, but what?

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code and for some reason could not get it to like using pandas for reading in the Excel spreadsheet.  I have had better luck using the "openpyxl" package.  If you have that package you might review the following sample program I built.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

data = load_workbook(filename = 'PriceOdometerV3.xlsx')

sheet_names = data.sheetnames
name = sheet_names[0]
sheet_ranges = data[name]
df_x = pd.DataFrame(sheet_ranges.values)

print(df_x)
```

Here was some sample output from a small spreadsheet that had two columns in it, Odometer Reading and Price.

```
==>python3 Excel.py 
                  0      1
0  Odometer Reading  Price
1            107338  10000
2             85000  14000
3            205777   5535
```

Perhaps that is an alternative you could use.  Hope that helps.

Regards.